# How to find Id which is used cross

Tags: sql

Assume that there is a table which is called Stack;

```
Id       StackId
-------------------
.             .
1             10
2             12
3             10
4             10
5             11
11            5
.             .
.             .
```

how to learn cross id like ?

```
Id = 5
StackId = 11

Id = 11
StackId = 5
```

I could not write the sql sentences which shows me

```
5,11
11,5
```

I dont know the numbers because the table has 1.000.000+ rows, so I want to find rows which likes 5,11

Comment: how exactly you want to show results? 1st sample or 2nd sample?

Comment: You are not really looking for `SELECT id, stackid FROM stack`, are you?

Comment: `select id, stackId from stack where id in (5,11)` would give you the second (last) result

Comment: I dont know the numbers because the table has 1.000.000+ rows, so I want to find rows which likes 5,11

Comment: Your question is not clear. I guess you are not in need of simple select query

Comment: what about two 5, 11 entries?

Comment: @techdo not possible, first row is a primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this with aggregation as well as a join.  Here is one method:

```
select (case when id < StackId then id else StackId end) as FirstVal,
       (case when id < StackId then StackId else id end) as SecondVal
from t
group by (case when id < StackId then id else StackId end),
         (case when id < StackId then StackId else id end)
having count(distinct id) = 2
```

If you have a database with a `least()` and `greatest()` functions, and you know there are now duplicates in the table, you can rephrase this as:

```
select least(id, StackId) as FirstVal, greatest(id, StackId) as SecondVal
from t
group by least(id, StackId), greatest(id, StackId)
having count(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `JOIN` to the table itself with `s1.Id = s2.StackId AND s1.StackId = s2.Id` condition:

```
SELECT s1.Id, s1.StackId
FROM Stack s1
JOIN Stack s2 ON s1.Id = s2.StackId AND s1.StackId = s2.Id
```

Because `INNER JOIN` is used (it's by default) rows with no corresponding `s2` values won't be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select a.* from 
    YourTable a inner join YourTable b on a.Id=b.StackId
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
select *
from Stack s
where exists (select 1 from Stack where Id = s.StackId and StackId = s.Id)
```